# Hiding a method for a related model

Tags: node.js, strongloop

How can I hide a method for a *related* model?

Let's say that, in the demo app [loopback-example-datagraph](https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-example-datagraph), I don't want to expose the `DELETE /customers/{id}/orders` method.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loopback 1.x, the relation is mapped to a prototype method internally. To not expose it as REST APIs, try the following:

```
var customer = app.models.Customer;
customer.prototype.__delete_orders.shared = false;
```

Comment: Where in the loopback-example-datagraph example would be the correct place to add this code. I'm having a tough time figuring out where exactly app.models.Customer is finally available.

Comment: You can add a js file in models folder, such as customer.js. The app can be required as `var app = require('../app');`

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer I Have Never Used StrongLoop**

Wild stab but it looks like this might work. When you add a relation it adds a method to the underlying model class. when you add a has many it adds this method

```
customer.orders.destroyAll(function(err) {
  ...
});
```

source: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Creating+model+relations#Creatingmodelrelations-Methodsaddedtothemodel.1

You should be able to say something like

```
var customer = app.models.Customer;
customer.orders.destroyAll.shared = false;
```